# Placing 2D Array from PostgreSQL Database into 2d List Python using Django Interface

Tags: python, django, list, postgresql

I'm attempting to retrieve information from a postgreSQL database, a single column to be specific within which the data is stored in a 2D array format

example :

```
('user1', 'user2,'user3'),('user1', 'user2,'user3'),('user1', 'user2,'user3')
```

I'm extracting the values into a `values_list` using django's database abstraction interface

```
q = DBReports.objects.all().filter(name__contains = name1)  
q = (q.values_list(columnName))
```

This then places all the values into a `values_list`, from this I need to extract two of the values from each list within the list, e.g `user1` and `user3` which are at array positions x,0,x,2 respectively, I am unable to determine how many lists within lists there will be, therefore I must iterate through the length

However I cannot convert the `values_list` to a 2D list, the following does not allow the code to be iteratable

```
list((q.values_list(columnName)))
```

And just returns a length of one, and all values in a single list.

Is there a way i can adequately extract this 2D list and place it into a 2D list within python?

Printed values are below (ignore all the '' its used later in the program)

```
[("[('user1', 'user2', 'user3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user4', 'user5', 'user6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user1', 'user3', 'user6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user1', 'user2', 'user7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user1', 'user2', 'user2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')]",)]
```

Comment: print q.values_list(columnName) for details.

Comment: @RajeshKaushik Thanks, See above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done like this

```
import ast
q = DBReports.objects.all().filter(name__contains = name1)  
q = (q.values_list(columnName))
users_list = ast.literal_eval(q[0][0])
```

Check the users_list value

```
print users_list
[('user1', 'user2', 'user3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user4', 'user5', 'user6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user1', 'user3', 'user6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user1', 'user2', 'user7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('user1', 'user2', 'user2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')]
```

This will enable iteration on users_list.

Note that ast.eval is **safe** to use. For more details read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) here.